# Is the slang phrase "wicked good" still used in New England?

Tags: american-english, slang

Once popular with young adults in the Boston area, wicked good simply meant "very good". I haven't been to that region for a long time and never heard it elsewhere.  Is it still current slang?

Comment: Actually, in New England, *"wicked"* means *"very"*, and it can be used for lots of adjectives besides *"good"*. [Evidence](http://www.boston.com/news/local/massachusetts/2014/07/03/turns-out-mensans-are-wicked-smaht-and-social/CbOMu4H6tcSEBAGKuXihRM/story.html).

Comment: I can attest to the currency of "wicked good". Heard somebody say it yesterday. Also have seen is used in texts/casual conversations from time to time.

Comment: It was more popular in the '90s than it is nowadays. It is no longer an *in* thing to say, though you'll still hear it quite often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears it is still used that way in New England:

[Wicked](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Wicked): New England slang that adds emphasis. Synonymous with really, very and hella. ( from Urban Dict.)

> - To describe how great something is: "This car is wicked cool!"
> - To show frustration: "That guy is wicked slow!"
> - To emphasize feelings: "That story made me wicked sad!"
> - To exaggerate your point: "That took a wicked long time!"
> - "That wicked cool car is wicked fast is owned by that wicked old guy, who drives it wicked slow when it's wicked hot out, which makes me wicked sad cause I'm wicked broke and I got to walk a wicked long way."

Comment: Still true in 2018.

Answer (score -1):

We would use the superlative "some wicked," which could stand alone, as in "that was some wicked."

Comment: add citation(s) to your answers if you please